# Using Border-bottom to Place A Hover/Active Link at the Bottom of the Menu Item

Tags: css, angular

How do I add an underline for an active or hovered link, where the underline shows up at the bottom of the menu bar it's a part of? With the code I currently I have (see below) the underline is showing up directly UNDERNEATH the menu bar, rather than showing up at the bottom of the menu bar. I tried using negative padding/margin, but that didn't work. Right now I have this:

```
.horiz-tab, .horiz-tab-active {
    background: @actionBar;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 1.5rem 1.125rem;
    position: relative;
}

a.horiz-tab:link, a.horiz-tab:visited {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a.horiz-tab:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: #4c7296 6px solid;
    overflow: none;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.tab-count {
    background-color: #689dcd;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .9rem;
    margin-left: 0.35rem;
    padding: 2px 6px;
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let record of records; let i = index;">
    <a routerLink="/organization" routerLinkActive="horiz-tab-active" class="horiz-tab">{{record._id.sub}}<span class="tab-count">{{record.count}}</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: We can't understand the issue or how your menu is laid out without HTML and/or additional CSS. If the border on the link is showing up below the bottom edge of the menu, it sounds like the element may be overflowing.

Comment: Added additional HTML and CSS.

Comment: We need a **working** [mcve]...angular code is not sufficient.

Comment: You have my HTML and my CSS. What else could I possibly provide in this instance?

Comment: you could mock up a plunker for us :) so we visually see the issue

Comment: The issue is pretty simple to visualize. My menu items have a background color. I want the hover link to place an underline at the bottom of the colored background of the menu item, but not beneath the colored background. Right now the border-bottom is showing up UNDERNEATH rather than at the bottom of the menu item's background color. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @BKD Yeah, see my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code a few minutes ago, because I had copied it in wrong. So your code doesn't line up with mine. But that said, are you saying the key is to use heights?

Comment: Cool. Got it to work. As your answer showed, the key was to use heights in both. Thanks!

Comment: @BKD No problem, and use `display:block` or `display: inline-block` on any `<a>` or `<span>` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has `.main` as a class in CSS yet there is none in HTML

```css
.horiz-menu {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  height: 34px;
  padding:6px 0 0 3px;
}
a.horiz-menu-tab:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #fb4;
  height:28px;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="horiz-menu" *ngFor="let record of records">
    <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="horiz-menu-active" class="horiz-menu-tab">{{info}}</a>
  </div>
```